Conga Composer: When I add an if condition, it will always add a massive blank lines even when condition is met
I have a table in a word document that is uploaded to Conga Composer as part of Salesforce CPQ:
SAMPLE -
Some Text here



A header
Another header




First
row


Second
row



...More rows...
This data is captured within an if condition:
{{TableStart:QLData}}
{IF   «SBQQ__QUOTELINE_PART_FAMILY» = "PART NUMBER" "
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
...More rows...
" ""
}
{{TableEnd:QLData}}

What happens when condition is met is this:

Some text here


14 Blank lines


Table


8 Blank Lines

When the condition is not met:

Some text


More than 14 blank lines

Expected outcome
If the condition is met, I only want to print the table out without the blank lines
If the condition is not met, I do not want anything to be printed nor blank lines, like as if the table did not exists and should continue with the rest of the document without a massive blank space/gap

It loos like the blank like is produced by the paragraph with IF condition. Have you tried moving the condition to the same paragraph as TableStart field?
Also it looks like you are using Aspose.Words and it's Mail Merge with Regions feature. If so, you can try using MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveEmptyParagraphs and MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveContainingFields:
https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.mailmerging/mailmergecleanupoptions/
